# Deploy application in EKS cluster from another EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-sdk-go

I am trying to deploy my application programmatically from one EKS cluster to all other EKS clusters. To do that I am getting kubeconfig details using clusterDescribe EKS api.
Steps in my code

1. Get name and region of EKS cluster
2. Describe EKS cluster using aws eks sdk
3. Using describe data, I am building kubeclient.
4. Using kubeclient, I can deploy application in EKS cluster.

The above steps work from my local machine for any EKS cluster in my account. but If I run my program from one EKS cluster(cluster1) to deploy my application into another(cluster2)
then I get a timeout error in my 4th step.

Can you help me what I am missing?

Comment: May be outbound traffic to internet ( to control plane ) is not allowed from nodes in cluster 1.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you planning but their are tools available which you can deploy on EKS and can do deployment on any kubernetes cluster, cloud accound etc.

`You should check Spinnaker open source tool for this`.

My team help companies to use spinnaker in their environments.